# Firebase are react-native backend

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, react-native-firebase

I have really been having a hard time intergrating firebase to my react-native UI.
Anyone who knows where(site, video or course) that one can learn how to use firebase as react native's backend?
Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use firebase as backend with their data base etc,

check out this blog https://rnfirebase.io/ , you will get to know about the different functionalities which you can integrate with firebase in RN